# MathJax enabled on page interferes with Rocket Loader

Tags: mathjax, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare as cdn service (Free). But when i use mathjax on any page it causes problem with rocket loader enabled.

Here is the link : http://www.e4exam.com/Questions/profit-and-loss

I am getting this when i enabled Rocket Loader 
[image: With Rocket Loader Enabled]

But when i disabled rocket loader it is ok.
[image: With Rocket Loader Disabled]

So is there any way to use MathJax with Rocket Loader enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rocket.js` file that Rocket Loader uses apparently replaces `<script>` tags in your page with its own object class, but this is not implemented in a way that is fully compatible with the native browser implementations.  MathJax uses `<script>` tags to store the math internally in the page, and these differences in implementation trip up MathJax.

One solution apparently is to add `data-cfasync="false"` to the `<script>` that loads MathJax.js (see [this MathJax issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1090) for details).